# Expanding $\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n-k)}$ as a polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial, stirling-numbers

I want to expand $\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n-k)}$ as a polynomial, where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function.

For $k\in\mathbb{N}$, it can be "simplified" as

$$\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n-k)}=(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\dots(n-k)$$

I was wondering if it were possible to expand that into $\sum_{i=0}^ka_in^{k-i}$ form.

Then, there is the harder case of $k\in\mathbb R$.

I imagined that it would be of the form $\Pi_{i=0}^\infty(n-r_i)$ where $r_n$ is the $n$th root.

If this were the case, we see that

$$\Gamma(n)\ne0\implies\frac1{\Gamma(n-k)}=0$$

This occurs at the poles

$$\implies r_i-k=-i$$

$$r_i=i+k$$

And put into product form

$$\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n-k)}=\Pi_{i=0}^\infty(n-r_i)=\Pi_{i=0}^\infty(n-k-i)$$

Sadly, I don't think it is possible to multiple the product out because it diverges.

- **Q1** Is there a polynomial/expanded form for $k\in\mathbb N$ using summations if needed?
- **Q2** What about $k\in\mathbb R$?

**EDIT**

From below, you can see I have worked the case for $k\in\mathbb N$, but I still need $k\in\mathbb R$.

$$\frac{\Gamma(u)}{\Gamma(u-n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}s(n,k)(u-n)^k$$

My assumption for $n\in\mathbb R$ is that the formula becomes

$$\frac{\Gamma(u)}{\Gamma(u-n)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{n-k}s(n,k)(u-n)^k$$

For similar reasons for why Euler extended binomial expansion the way he did.  I note that my proposed formula holds true if $n\in\mathbb N$, but doesn't make much sense for $n\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: See Pochhammer symbol (or maybe it's spelled Pochammer, or Pochamer, or something else).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well, that was simple.  :(  Wikipedia does not give explicit polynomial form.  But wolfram alpha does.  Thank you.

Comment: The question is still open for $k\in\mathbb R$

Comment: @GerryMyerson : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, but it does not show the expanded form as a polynomial.

Comment: @SimpleArt I don't have access to the article, but it looks like this paper studies exactly your question with the same goal of generalizing Stirling numbers (a.k.a. the coefficients of the series) to the fractional setting: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03322642

Comment: @SimpleArt It looks like the full-text of the above article may be available here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257289572_Factorial_functions_and_Stirling_numbers

Comment: @SimpleArt In particular it looks like equation (5.2) will be of primary interest to you.  Also note that per (1.7) the convergence of the infinite series has only been justified for $|u-n| < 1$, which I suppose isn't different from the binomial expansion case.

Comment: @ErickWong Sorry, the loading is really really slow...

Comment: @SimpleArt Maybe you'll have better luck with the "Download full-text" button?  Less back-and-forth bandwidth required, I would think.

Comment: @ErickWong So $s(a,k)=\sum_{j=k}^\infty\binom ajs(j,k)s(a-j,0)$.  Thanks for the nice link.  It appears as though $s(a-j,0)=0$?

Comment: @SimpleArt Sorry, I guess (5.1) works better as a definition (since $a-j$ is still fractional).  $s(a,k) = \Gamma(a+1) \sum_{j=k}^\infty \frac{s(j,k)}{j!} \frac{\sin \pi(a-j)}{\pi(a-j)}$.

Comment: @ErickWong Ok, that makes much more sense.  I'll see where that takes me.

Answer (score 3):

As [WolframAlpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) states:

$$\frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{\Gamma(x)}=x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\dots(x+n-1)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}s(n,k)x^k$$

where $s(n,k)$ is a Stirling number of the first kind.

Rewritable as

$$x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\dots(x+n-1)=(x+n-1)(x+n-2)(x+n-3)\dots x=\frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{\Gamma(x+n-n)}$$

Use substitution $x+n=u$

$$=\frac{\Gamma(u)}{\Gamma(u-n)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $\frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{\Gamma(x)}=(x)_n$, the answer is simply given by the [generating function for Stirling numbers of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheFirstKind.html).

Comment: Yes, I was reading that, but I couldn't understand it for $h\notin\mathbb N$, assuming we are both referring to the bottom of the link.

Comment: @SimpleArt: I was simply referring to identity $(8)$.

Comment: If $n\notin\mathbb N$, then the upper bound to the summation becomes $\infty$?  And even if that were the case, how do I evaluate individual values, as they are within the summation?  (I'm actually expecting answers to be towards my last question in the post)

Comment: @SimpleArt: the upper bound of which summation? We just have a ratio of two $\Gamma$ functions, that is well-defined as soon as their parameters do not belong to $\{0,-1,-2,\ldots\}$. If $x\in\mathbb{N}$, such a ratio is a polynomial in the variable $x$ with degree $n$. If $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\mathbb{N}$, the substitution $x=z+n$ does the trick. There is an obvious parallel with the binomial series and the negative binomial series.

Comment: I was referring to identity $(8)$, where the summation on the left does not make sense for $n\notin\mathbb N$.$$\sum_{k=0}^ns(n,k)x^k=(x)_n?$$

Comment: @SimpleArt: if $n\not\in\mathbb{N}$ then $(x)_n$ is not a polynomial in $x$, hence which coefficients are you looking for?

Comment: I was wondering if it then become something along the lines of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty s(n,k)x^k=(x)_n$.  This holds true for $n\in\mathbb N$, since $s(n,k)=0$ if $k>n$ and $k\in\mathbb N$

Comment: @SimpleArt: if you extend the definition of $s(n,k)$ for $n\not\in\mathbb{N}$, that holds for sure, but you need an analytic continuation.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I'm getting some of that from comments above.

Answer (score 1):

In particular, for $\displaystyle k=\frac{1}{2}$,

\begin{align*}
  \Gamma \left( n-\frac{1}{2} \right) &= \frac{(2n-3)!!}{2^{n-1}} \sqrt{\pi} \\
  \frac{\Gamma \left( n \right)}{\Gamma \left( n-\frac{1}{2} \right)} &=
  \frac{(n-1)!}{(2n-3)!!} \frac{2^{n-1}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \\
  &= \frac{(n-1)!(2n-2)!!}{(2n-2)!!(2n-3)!!} \frac{2^{n-1}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \\
  &= \frac{2^{n-1} [(n-1)!]^{2}}{(2n-2)!} \frac{2^{n-1}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \\
  &= \frac{2^{2(n-1)}}{\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\sqrt{\pi}} \\
  &= \frac{2^{2(n-1)}(n-1)!}{(2n-2)(2n-3) \ldots n \sqrt{\pi}}
\end{align*}

which is not a polynomial in $n$.

By $\displaystyle \Gamma \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)=
2^{7/9}3^{-1/12} \sqrt[3]{\pi K(\sin 15^{\circ})}$, we can do the something similar for $k=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: I have to ask, is there a general solution for $k=\frac1a$?

Comment: Until now, only particular values of fraction $x$ in which $\Gamma(x)$ are known.  May refer http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html

Comment: Thanks.  I thought as much, considering $\Gamma(1/2)$ and $\Gamma(1/3)$ don't have an obvious form.