# Factorials division formula

Tags: factorial, gamma-function

$$x!/(x+1)! = 1/(x+1)$$

$$x!/(x+2)! = 1/(x+1)(x+2)$$

$$x!/(x+3)! = 1/(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$$

$$ \vdots $$

in general $x!/(x+i)! = (x!/(x+i-1)!)(1/(x+i))$

but what would be the equation for $x!/(x+1/3)!$ 
 ??

I tried expanding the first equations (1/polynomial) and trying to apply the pattern to non-integers. It didn´t work so much.

For example, in the polynomials formed by $(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n)$ the first term will always be $x^n$, the second will be $(n(n+1)/2)x^n/x$ since it is the sum of choosing $(n-1)$ "$x$´s" so that you will end adding $1x^m+2x^m+3x^m+\cdots$,  $m=n-1$. And so I approximated $x!/(x+3/2)!$ to $1/(x^1x^.5+(15/8)x^.5)$.

(Having trouble writing the equations if someone correct them that would be really nice), but I wasn´t able to anything else.

I also tried using the gamma function in the form of a convergent infinite sum, but nothing useful came out of that.

Ant thoughts would really appreciated.

Comment: If you want to be strict, then $!$ is only used on non-negative integers and so at least one of $x$ or $x+\frac{1}{3}$ will not be an integer and thus there is no meaning to the expression $\frac{x!}{(x+\frac{1}{3})!}$.  If you were to refer instead to the gamma function (so that you allow non-integer inputs) you would have $\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+\frac{4}{3})}$.  Simplifying further might not be explicitly possible, but for large $x$ this is approximately $x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$

Comment: What even is $3.5!?$

Comment: @Simple, that's what the Gamma function is for.

Comment: Here you go?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802862/expanding-frac-gamman-gamman-k-as-a-polynomial

Answer (score 1):

1. One thing that comes to mind is the triplication formula
   $$ \Gamma(3z) ~=~\frac{3^{3z-\frac{1}{2}}}{2\pi}\Gamma(z)\Gamma\left(z+\frac{1}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(z+\frac{2}{3}\right) \tag{6.1.19} $$
   for the [Euler Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), cf. Abramowitz and Stegun, eq. (6.1.19), p. 256. If we define the notation $$z!~:=~\Gamma(z+1),$$ then eq. (6.1.19) becomes
   $$ (3z+2)! ~=~\frac{3^{3z+\frac{5}{2}}}{2\pi}z!\left(z+\frac{1}{3}\right)!\left(z+\frac{2}{3}\right)!~. $$
   OP's expression then becomes
   $$\frac{z!}{\left(z+\frac{1}{3}\right)!}
   ~=~\frac{3^{3z+\frac{5}{2}}}{2\pi}\frac{(z!)^2}{(3z+2)! } \left(z+\frac{2}{3}\right)!~.$$
2. The reciprocal
   $$\frac{\left(z+\frac{1}{3}\right)!}{z!}~=:~(z\!+\!1)_{1/3}$$
   is a generalized Pochhammer symbol.