# looking for the coefficients of a special polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

$n\in\mathbb{N}_0$

$$x^{n+1}\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n (t+k)}{(t+x)^{n+2}}dt$$

is a polynomial of $x$ with degree $n$.

The coefficients of this polynomial are related to the Stirling numbers of the first kind.

But I don't know the exact values or at least a recursion.

Comment: The product can be expanded with Stirling numbers or condensed with the gamma function: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802862/expanding-frac-gamman-gamman-k-as-a-polynomial Also, one may rewrite as $$\frac1x\int_0^\infty\frac{\Gamma(t+n+1)}{\Gamma(t+1)\left(\frac tx+1\right)^{n+2}}dx$$

Comment: @Simple Art: Thanks for your hint. But please: It's $dt$ not $dx$. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the product might be written as $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}c(n,k)t^{k-1}$ where $c(n,k)$ are the [unsigned Stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind). We then have to calclulate the (exercise: show convergence) integral

$$
\int_0^{\infty}dt\frac{t^{k-1}}{(t+x)^{n+2}}=\frac{1}{x^{n-k+2}}\int_0^{\infty}dq\frac{q^{k-1}}{(1+q)^{n+2}}=\\
\frac{1}{x^{n-k+2}}B(k,n-k+2)\quad \text{with}\,\,k \in1,...,n+1
$$

here $B(x,y)$ denotes Eulers Beta function.

therefore your complete expression reads

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}c(n,k)B(k,n-k+2)x^{k-1}
$$

with explicit expressions for the coefficents

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! But I think it's not so complicate, I am thinking about a polynomial of $t+x$ of the counter.

Comment: sorry, i don't get your point. u want a polynomial in the variable $(x+k)$?

Comment: Now I think it's the best to substitute $t+k$ by $(t+x)+(k-x)$ and to develope the product into a polynomial of $t+x$ so that it can devided by $(t+x)^{n+2}$.

Comment: why do you think this makes things simpler?

Comment: The last term (without $t$) is not touched by the integral because of $dt$ (not $dx$). There are only terms left with $(t+x)^{-k}$.

Comment: but you still have to do the product to get a doable integral

Comment: Yes, that's right. But then the integral is no problem any more.

Comment: you have to deal with beta integrals (which are not too hard) anyway so i really don't see the simplifcation

Comment: O.k., I think your are right, perhaps I would choose a longer way with the same result. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: you are very welcome, thanks for the interesting question